# Application hanging after calling route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to build a plugin to connect to my Freshbooks account through their API. I've managed to set up my connection to the API, but as soon as I make my request (I can see the "Made the request!" in console) the application the application just hangs. I can see in the console that my request is made but then nothing happens. Is it still waiting for the response?

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("landing");
});

//setup the parameters for connecting to freshbooks api using simple-oauth2 library
const oauth2 = simpleOauthModule.create({
    client: {
        id: process.env.FRESHBOOKS_CLIENT_ID,
        secret: process.env.FRESHBOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    auth: {
        tokenHost: config.freshbooks.token_host,
        tokenPath: config.freshbooks.toke_path,
        authorizePath: config.freshbooks.authorize_path,
    },
    options: {
        bodyFormat: 'json',
        authorizationMethod: 'body',
    },
});

//authorization uri definition
const authorizationUri = oauth2.authorizationCode.authorizeURL({
    redirect_uri: 'https://localhost/callback'
});

//initial page redirecting to freshbooks
router.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
    //console.log('--DEBUG-- Inside /auth');
    console.log('--DEBUG-- Authorization URI: ' + authorizationUri);
    res.redirect(authorizationUri);
});

//callback service parsing the authorization token and asking for access token
// router.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
router.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    //console.log('--DEBUG-- Inside /freshbooks');
    //const code = req.query.code;

    //set the authorization code into the environment variables
    config.freshbooks.auth_code = req.query.code;
    console.log('--DEBUG-- Authorization Code: ' + config.freshbooks.auth_code);

    //set the specific headers required by freshbooks as per documentation
    var headers = {
        'Api-version': 'alpha',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer'
    };

    //set the data needed for getting token from freshbooks api
    var data = {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: process.env.FRESHBOOKS_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.FRESHBOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET,
        code: config.freshbooks.auth_code,
        redirect_uri: 'https://localhost/callback'
    };

    //set the options for the request to get token
    var options = {
        url: config.freshbooks.token_host + config.freshbooks.token_path, 
        headers: headers, 
        method: 'GET', 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        console.log('--DEBUG-- Made the request!');
        if (!error && !(res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)) {
            console.log('--DEBUG-- Authorization Token Response: ' + data);

            //set the access and refresh tokens in the environment variables
            var tokens = JSON.parse(body);
            config.freshbooks.access_token = tokens.access_token;
            config.freshbooks.refresh_token = tokens.refresh_token;
        } else {
            error = new Error('--HTTP Error-- Authorization Token: ' + res.statusCode + ': ' + body);
        }
    }

    //request access token from freshbooks api
    request(options, callback);
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your callback doesn’t appear to send a response.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks! Where should I return my response, inside my callback() function? I'm confused how to return back to the request but still executing my 'if' section.

Comment: Yes, inside the callback. It’s not returning the response, but writing it. Make sure to write a response in the error case, too, or pass the error to `next`.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused what should I return? Since I am not interested in the values as I am writing them to a config file, is there something I should return?

Comment: I’m not familiar with the Freshbooks API, but if the callback doesn’t say it expects a response you can just `response.end()` in both cases, and log the error in the error case.

Comment: Thanks! In my case since I am saving the values to a config file, I will just use end(). If you move your comment to an answer I will mark it. Thank you for the help!